# If a PRNG has a long enough sequence of numbers, why can it be bruteforced?

Tags: random, numbers, sequence, seed

I read that the seed needs to be unpredictable in a pseudo-random generation, because if they could narrow down the possible seed to a reasonable amount of different values, a brute-force attack would be possible.

This confuses me however. Imagine if I use an algorithm that generates pseudo-random numbers. In theory they will cycle at some point, but in practice this apparently seldom happens according to many people. 
If that's the case, let's say an attacker has narrowed the seed down to 50k different seeds (the attacker knows that the seed is one of these 50k seeds). And the attacker also has a login cookie based on this random generator (the attacker knows the algorithm which makes the login cookies).

If the attacker then checks every seed value of these 50k possible seeds and compares the result to his own login cookie in order to pinpoint the seed used... What guarantees are there that the login cookie generated by the attacker uses the same values from the pseudo-random sequence as the login cookie? What if the pseudo random generator uses the "last" numbers in the sequence before the cycle on this particular login cookie. Wouldn't this force the attacker to iterate billions of times (or more) for each seed to try since the attacker needs to try every possible value the PRNG can generate?

A pseudo-random sequence of numbers is after all random, as long as it's infinite or close to infinite without a cycle.

Hope I could make my question clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One assumes that the victim has only just seeded their PRNG immediately before generating a cookie for the attacker.  The attacker simulates that program (just the bits it cares about) with all of its possible seeds.  When the attacker's simulation emits the same values as the victim sent then the attacker assumes that their simulation is in the same state as the victim and that further simulation will reveal what the victim is going to do next.

If the seed was set a very long time ago and it's not known to the attacker how many calls to `rand()` (or equivalent) have been made, then that simulation eventually becomes impossible as it has to try all the possible permutations of control flow leading up to the generation of the cookie.

In a *different* kind of attack, where a PRNG has a short period (and consequently a small state space), the attacker can ignore the seed and instead through the entire state space of the PRNG to try to force it to emit the same output.  Then it doesn't matter how long ago the victim used the seed.

Comment: Why can't they design the PRNGs such that the sequence is randomly picked (for example from the middle), instead of starting from the "beginning" every time? Wouldn't that make it more unprectable?

Comment: A lot of straightforward PRNGs are just one big long loop of predictable random numbers, and their seed is exactly that random choice of where to start.  That's why correctly guessing the seed tells you exactly what's going to happen next.